# Get value from ChangeListener with stateChanged on JSlider

Tags: java, jslider

I would like to keep the value changed from my JSlider. 
My slider has for goal to change the thickness of a line in a canvas and I want to save the value from this slider...

When I do that :

```
slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            val = ((JSlider)event.getSource()).getValue();
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    });
```

I get all values that have been changed when moving the slider

```
  8
  6
  13
```

But I want to do this :

```
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            val = ((JSlider)event.getSource()).getValue();
           -> smth = val;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(smth) // that I want : gives the last value changed.
    System.out.println(smth)  // that I don't want : print 0
```

Then I could re-use this value.

I use this to put the value on a JLabel that changes when one moves the slider.

Full code :

```
    int initValue = 1;
    int minimum = 1;
    int maximum = 20;
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, minimum, maximum, initValue);
    slider.setInverted(true);
    slider.setUI(new MySliderUI(slider) {
        @Override
        public TrackListener createTrackListener(JSlider slider) {
            return new TrackListener() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    JSlider slider = (JSlider) e.getComponent();
                    slider.setValue(valueForYPosition(e.getY()));
                    labelSize.setText(slider.getValue()+"");
                    //TODO SAVE VALUE
                    super.mousePressed(e); // isDragging = true;
                    super.mouseDragged(e);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldScroll(int direction) {
                    return false;
                }

            };
        }
    });

    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            val = ((JSlider)event.getSource()).getValue();
            System.out.println(val); // 8 12 7 ...
        }
    });
    System.out.println(val); // 0
    slider.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Size"));
    slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 600));

    tailleColor.add(slider);
    tailleColor.add(labelSize);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want val to be 0?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear. I dont want the value to be 0 but it is what I get..